# Having problems creating a range for "NoneType"

Tags: python, range, coordinates, nonetype

I am a student trying to create a range of coordinates for a ball detector on pi-top 4.

```
    if blue_ball.found:
            print(f"Blue ball center: {blue_ball.center}")
            print()   
        
     if ((30,50) <= blue_ball.center <= (60, 80)):
            led.on()
            sleep(0.5)`
```

The second block is where I am running into issues. I get an error that

> "<=" cannot be inbetween a tuple and a NoneType.

I have tried defining it as an integer and replacing it with "{blue_ball.center}" as it appears earlier in an f-string. I think it returns as NoneType because it originates from "BallDetector" from pitop.processing.algorithms, which is prewritten and which I know nothing about. I have a feeling that the coordinate ranges are not formatted correctly, but mainly I want to know how to recall the "color_ball.center" without getting an error. I would greatly appreciate any insight whether or not it fixes my problem, and I am aware that my coding skills are not amazing so I appreciate any sort of criticism.

I tried defining it as an integer, but I can't because it isn't a string or number. I tried rewriting it as it appears in a prewritten f-string but that is still a NoneType. I am not even sure what I expected because I don't really understand why it is a NoneType.

Comment: Once you've fixed the problem with the center being None, your range check still isn't going to do what you want - `(30,50) <= center <= (60, 80)` would be true for `(40, 4000000)` for example, because the second element of the tuples is only considered in a comparison when the first element is equal.  You need to write two separate range checks, one for each coordinate.

Comment: Where the code says `((30,50) <= blue_ball.center <= (60, 80))`, **what do you think this should mean, and why**? What do you think will be the value of `blue_ball.center`, and why? Did you try to check this? How? What result did you get for `blue_ball.center`?

Comment: I notice that you have some code that checks whether `blue_ball.found`. If the ball is found, will it have a center position? Will it have a center position if it not found? Therefore, are there conditions for when the next part of the code should run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Ball.center` is `None` if the ball has not been detected. There's even a property specifically for testing that:

```
    @property
    def found(self) -> bool:
        """
        :return: Boolean to determine if a valid ball was found in the frame.
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return self.center is not None
```

So, you might want to test something like

```
if blue_ball.found and (30,50) <= blue_ball.center <= (60, 80):
```

I'm not certain that is exactly right for your code, it depends what you want to do if the ball isn't there. You haven't shown enough context for me to really guess. You might need to add an `else` clause to your `if`, if you need to actually *do something* in that case, rather than just skipping whatever the body of the `if` has.